# iOS App rejected by Apple, even after adding "Restore Purchase" feature?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, xcode8

In my app i have in app purchase feature. I have added Restore purchase functionality in the app. I have shown a Restore Purchase Button in the app, so user can restore all his previous purchases on tapping the button.

But i am getting this error from resolution center as **Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase**

The error description says we must include a Restore purchase button and functionality. Which I already included in the app.

My code is working perfectly. I tested with sandbox tester accounts. So if I purchase some items and and after that uninstall the app and again if I reinstall the app and after tapping restore purchase button all the previously purchased items for that sandbox test user unlocks.

Here is my code snippet:

```
-(void)sendreciptToApple{
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];


// Create the JSON object that describes the request
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *requestContents = @{
                                  @"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]
                                  };
NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                      options:0
                                                        error:&error];

if (!requestData) { /* ... Handle error ... */ }

// Create a POST request with the receipt data.
// NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"]; //for sandbox

NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"]; // for live


// https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
// https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
[storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

// Make a connection to the iTunes Store on a background queue.
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:storeRequest queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           if (connectionError) {
                               /* ... Handle error ... */
                           } else {
                               NSError *error;
                               NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
                               if (!jsonResponse) { /* ... Handle error ...*/ }
                               [self isAppPreviouslyPurchased:jsonResponse];

                               [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                                   // update the UI here
                                   //   [self fireAllProductPurchaseOnetime];
                                   [self showViewsAfterOrBeforePurchase];
                                   [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                               }];
                           }
                       }];

    }
```

I am parsing and saving the JSON response from apple and storing locally..

```
-(void)isAppPreviouslyPurchased:(NSDictionary *)receipt{
NSLog(@"after receive reciept data %@",receipt);


NSMutableArray *purchasedItemArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[receipt valueForKeyPath:@"receipt.in_app"]];

NSLog(@"Already purchased item array<<<<>>>>>> %@",purchasedItemArray);
NSString *valueToSave = @"yes";

if (purchasedItemArray.count>0)
{
    for (int i=0; i<purchasedItemArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *productItem=[purchasedItemArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *productID=[productItem valueForKey:@"product_id"];

        if ([productID isEqualToString: @"com.iwonderapp.iWonder.EntireApp"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"IsAllProductPurchased"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
        if ([productID isEqualToString: @"com.iwonderapp.iWonder.Organs"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"IsOrgansPurchased"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
        if ([productID isEqualToString: @"com.iwonderapp.iWonder.Endocrines"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"IsEndocrinesPurchased"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
        if ([productID isEqualToString: @"com.iwonderapp.iWonder.Emotions"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"IsEmotionsPurchased"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        }
        if ([productID isEqualToString: @"com.iwonderapp.iWonder.SexIntInf"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"IsIntimacyPurchased"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
        if ([productID isEqualToString: @"com.iwonderapp.iWonder.ConOverCon"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"IsConflictOverwhelmPurchased"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
        if ([productID isEqualToString: @"com.iwonderapp.iWonder.PowConMan"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"IsPowerControlPurchased"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
        if ([productID isEqualToString: @"com.iwonderapp.iWonder.CreExpRej"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"IsCreativityPurchased"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
        if ([productID isEqualToString: @"com.iwonderapp.iWonder.Chakras"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"IsChakrasPurchased"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }

    }
}



 }
```

Comment: Have you told Apple where to find the Restore Purchases button?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably your issue:

```
// NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"]; //for sandbox

NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"]; // for live
```

When Apple tests your IAP flow it happens in the sandbox environment. **You are sending the sandbox receipt to the production URL**. This will obviously not work, you'll receive status code `21007`. When you detect that status code you know you have to send it to the sandbox URL.

That's how Apple recommends to handle this: *always* send the receipt to the production URL first, and if you receive status code `21007` send it to the sandbox URL as a fallback.

#### Useful links

- [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html) (take a look at Table 2-1: Status codes)